# Can I remove correlated features before cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, cross-validation

I am working on a high-imbalanced (80-20 ratio), high-dimensional dataset (200 sample size, 300 features) where all variables are highly correlated. Can I remove the perfectly correlated (using Pearson's correlation coefficient) variables (6 variables) before cross-validation? Does this cause any information leakage?

Answer (score 0):

Removing *perfectly* correlated variables (pairwise Pearson coefficient) is fine. It's like removing a constant feature.

Comment: What, exactly, are "perfectly correlated variables"?  It seems obvious until you contemplate higher-dimensional problems in which, say, $300$ features with $200$ observations might yield a rank-$100$ matrix.  Which variables ought to be removed and why?  Indeed, what is getting cross-validated in this context?  Do the correlations include those between the "variables" and some unstated response variable or do they include only correlations among the explanatory variables alone? There's an awful lot that matters here which is left to the imagination!

Comment: I believe I've just assumed +/-1 Pearson correlation coefficient between two features, i.e. linear dependence.

Comment: Isn't the question about *300* features, not just two? Their covariance matrix can have rank as small as $2$ without *any* correlation coefficient being close to $\pm 1.$

Comment: @whuber It's the Pearson correlation coefficient between the feature variables (+/-1). The Pearson correlation between the feature variables and the response (binary) is very low (less than 0.3). I am doing the cross-validation to tune hyper-parameters for prediction (binary classification) using machine learning algorithms that include logistic regression, random forest, xgboost,...etc

Comment: The standard approach is to regularize the problem (*e.g.*, using a Lasso or Bayesian method) rather than proposing some *ad hoc* method of removing variables.  But you appear to contradict yourself: at one point you refer to "300 features" and later you refer to "6 variables".  Are "variables" and "features" the same or not? (For some people, a "variable" is a group of features.)  Note, too, that inevitably there will be *at least* 300 - 200 = 100 features that are *perfectly linearly dependent* on the remaining features.

Comment: Perfectly valid points. At least, I've tried to make my point clear by just considering pairwise correlations (assuming it was being asked). But, a more general treatment of linear dependence between groups of features requires the covariance matrix to be accounted and is more complicated than what I've just scribbled.

Comment: @whuber I am using features and variables synonymously. Out of 300 variables, Pearson correlation = 1.0  for 6 variables,  correlation > 0.99 for 91 variables, and correlation > 0.95 for 188 variables.